# Tikzposter + biblatex alignment of references

Tags: biblatex, tikzposter

I am using biblatex numeric style in combination with tikzposter and for references that span more than one line the text does not align properly. I have tried the minipage environment but it does not seem to help either.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\begin{columns}
\column{.2}
\block{References}{
\nocite{*}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{center}\mbox{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, `\settowidth` does not work as intended with `tikzposter` in all contexts. In particular the command returns `0pt` unless invoked within a `block`.

With a modern `biblatex` a quick workaround would be to use the `locallabelwidth` option, which defers length calculations to the actual `\printbibliography` and only takes the entries actually appearing in that bibliography into account.

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=numeric, sorting=none, locallabelwidth]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

\begin{columns}
\column{.2}
\block{References}{
\nocite{sigfridsson,worman}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{center}\mbox{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

[image: Neatly aligned bibliography]